# Android Emulator Error in windows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I installed android studio 2.0 on my windows 7 ultimate, and I installed all the packages required by the android also the HAXM package is also installed. When I tried to run the emulator, it didn't run, a message popped up that said vt-x should be enabled in bios security settings, this is the pic.

[image: vt-x error]

I went in the bios settings but the Virtualization was already enabled over there, but when I installed a software called speccy to know about what all is included in my computer and I found in the cpu section showing that virtualization is supported but it is  disabled.

Also when I ran the emulator it was written on top that /dev/kvm is not found I searched for it but it was related to linux distro I have provided some screenshots of that error this is the pic.

[image: error while launching avd]

Comment: After enabling BIOS settings, did you install the HAXM separately, from `\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` folder?

Comment: I went in the bios setting but the virtualization was already enabled n i went back to install the haxm also but it gaved an error that failed to configure driver :unknown errror,failed to open driver

Comment: Same here. But no surprise: The emulator on windows 7 is just sluggish, buggish and unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Go to BIOS setting of your PC after restart. Then enable virtualization in your BIOS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday and I solved it by following the instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206410). I did the following:

- Uninstalled *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) 6.0.1* from Android Studio: use Tools->Android->SDK Manager->Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK, select the tab *SDK Tools*, uncheck *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator* and press *Apply*;
- Closed Android Studio;
- Uninstalled *Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager* from Control Panel->Program and Features;
- Opened Android Studio and re-installed *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator* from the same menu in Tools->Android->SDK Manager->Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK.

Alternatively, one can use the *Launch Standalone SDK Manager*, open the *Extras* folder, check *Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator* and press *Delete 1 package* (or *Install*).

It seems that my installation of Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) was corrupted. It is located under:

```
    C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend trying Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/ very fast, optimized and easy to kick-start

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).