# Cannot run Android Emulator in Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I just re-installed Android Studio 2.1.1 on the same PC running Windows 7 32-bit after a year. Everything other than the emulator works perfectly.

The AVD Manager displays an error message: `/dev/kvm is not found.`
When I click on the Troubleshoot button, it says

> Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux
> distro has working KVM module.

Also, when I try running an emulator, an error pops up saying

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
>
> /dev/kvm is not found.
>
> Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has
> working KVM module.

I have disabled VT-x, but I can't find Hyper-V anywhere on my PC.
Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) is installed.
After looking for solutions online, I tried to install HAXM manually using the installer available on their website ([Installer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)) but I got an error saying

> Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver

Here are some of the StackOverflow questions that I referred to:

[Android Emulator Error in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547957/android-emulator-error-in-windows/36548766)

[HAXM installed successfully, but not recognized by Android Studio 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140005/haxm-installed-successfully-but-not-recognized-by-android-studio-2-1)

[Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

Answer (score 6):

Your machine might not even support Virtualization.
 To fix this, you just have to run the emulator with the system image *armeabi*.
 Go to your Android Virtual Device Manager, and create a new device. Select your hardware, then click next. Here, it is very important to select a system image with the ABI column saying *"armeabi"* or *"armeabi-v7a"*. It should look like this:[image]
Continue with the steps, and your emulator should work and run properly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens due to two factors:

1. VT-x is not enabled in the Bios and Intel Virtualization Technology is not enabled in the Bios.

   Solution: In your BIOS, go to Advanced Mode -> CPU Configuration -> Intel Virtual Technology and Enable it. Go back to Advanced and find your way to the VT-x option and enable it.
2. The SDK tool called: Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) is installed in the SDK Manager.

   Solution: It is only an installer and we have to install the tool manually by double-clicking the actual installer in the location:
   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager. Double-click the file haxm_check.exe and install the tool.

Restart your Android Studio and run the Emulator.